# Sort rows in DataGridView

Tags: arrays, vb.net, winforms, sorting, datagridview

I have an array of objects bounded to DataGridView (VB.NET). In some interval attributes in objects are changing. I need to have rows in DataGridView sorted. I don´t want to have array sorted because it is important to know on which index objects are stored in array. I just want to have rows sorted.

In the fact I don´t need to have sorted rows but in the case some object in array is null, this row is empty and I don´t want to have empty rows in the middle of the table. I need to have full rows in the beggining and empty rows in the bottom.

I know I can use a list but I really need array because to know index of o object is important. Maybe there is property to don´t show empty lines? Thank you guys!

Comment: You could populate a DataTable with the values you want in your DataGridView. You then create a DataView and assign the DataTable to `DataView1.Table` ... Then you assign your DataView1 to your DataGridView and voila, you can sort / filter / search whilst keeping track of your data (indexes).

Comment: Isn´t there easier way how to achieve that?